# Which method of Roles repository Symfony uses to load Roles entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have my Users and Roles in the database loaded according to Symfony Security chapter. Users implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable,
Roles implements RoleInterface.
My Roles entity:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Roles:
   type:     entity
   table:     Roles
   repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\Roles
[...]
     oneToMany:
          users:
               targetEntity:     Users
               mappedBy:          role
               cascade:           [persist]
          privs:
               targetEntity:     RolesPrivileges
               mappedBy:          role
               cascade:           [persist]
```

My RolesPrivileges entity is connected with many to one relation with Roles and the same kind of relation to Privileges:

```
AppBundle\Entity\RolesPrivileges:
     type:     entity
     table:     RolesPrivileges
     repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\RolesPrivileges
id:
    role:
           associationKey: true
           type:     integer
    privilege:
           type:     integer
           associationKey: true
 fields:
    related:
           type:     boolean
           nullable:   FALSE
           options:
                  default:    0
 manyToOne:
      role:
           targetEntity:     Roles
           inversedBy:      privs
           joinColumn:
                name:     role_id
                referencedColumnName:     id
      privilege:
           targetEntity:     Privileges
           joinColumn:
                name:     privilege_id
                referencedColumnName:     id
```

And finally Privileges entity:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Privileges:
     type:     entity
         table:     Privileges
         id:
[...]

       fields:
           short:
               type:     string
               length:    50
               nullable:    FALSE
```

I wrote it like that to be able to check for detailed access right (of a logged in user) to each action in Controller. I simply iterate through the privileges that are related to a Role that is assigned to a User.

The problem is Symfony is doing separate queries to db for each of the entry from the Privileges table. I fixed it in the Controller by fetching it all using a query and storing in a protected variable.

But I don't know how to fix the same problem that occurs when I iterate through the privileges from a twig template (using a method defined in Roles entity). I was thinking I can redefine one of the methods in RolesRepository to be able to fetch all the privileges in one query. How can I do that?

Comment: The only solution (and it's ugly) that comes to my mind is to redefine render() method of a Controller and pass the privileges variable (previously populated from the db, one query) to twig template and iterate through that. But I'm looking for a nicer fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relations are lazy-loaded by default in Doctrine. If you always want to load the privileges along with the roles when these are fetched configure the type of load of the relation as EAGER.

> Whenever you query for an entity that has persistent associations and
>   these associations are mapped as EAGER, they will automatically be
>   loaded together with the entity being queried and is thus immediately
>   available to your application.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

```
AppBundle\Entity\Roles:
    oneToMany:
        [...]
        privs:
            [...]
            fetch: EAGER

AppBundle\Entity\RolesPrivileges:
    [...]
    manyToOne:
        privilege:
            [...]
            fetch: EAGER
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefano. As you can see in the RolesPrivileges entity snippet, I've got additional field and thus I need to have separate entity.
Also, does't fetch:EAGER just make the associated entities load immediately, but still in separate queries? I just wanted to reduce the number of queries...

Comment: I didn't notice the additional field you have in the middle entity, sorry about that. By the way, by default Doctrine does a query to fetch each record of the collection. EXTRA_LAZY would instead skip loading of all records if you (for example) only want to count the number of items of the collection. Finally, EAGER loading fetch the entities by loading all rows in a single query

Comment: Well, I've tested EAGER loading but unfortunately it still does load it all one by one (and it's over 100 queries in case you wonder why I want to fix this). Maybe it is the way I use the data (iteration) that makes doctrine query db that way. Do you think the method it uses is findOneBy? I'd like to redefine it in my Repository class.

Comment: Which entities are being loaded one by one? The RolesPrivilege or the Privilege entities? Because I used EAGER multiple times in different projects and I'm sure it works, so maybe there is something I'm missing out in your code

Comment: The Privilege entities are being loaded one by one.

Comment: Did you set the privilege relation of the RolesPrivilege entity to fetch in EAGER mode?

Comment: No, I just set EAGER for 'privs' in Roles. Now that I checked it for 'privileges' in RolesPrivileges, I can see it really works as you wrote before. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the missing part of the example code and I've removed the suggestion about the auto-generated many-to-many entity that does not apply to your case